# How to fix "Warning! Now system is in safe mode. Please re-setting CPU frequency in CMOS setup" error?

Tags: boot, bios

This doesn't seem to be a common error, but of the places where it is cataloged, there are none that seem to have any kind of fix or workaround, other than replacing your motherboard.

The error is a black screen before boot up that looks something like this:

[image: "Warning! Now system is in safe mode. Please re-setting CPU frequency in CMOS setup" black screen error]

The important text of the message is:

> CMOS checksum error - Defaults loaded
>   Warning! Now system is in safe mode.
>   Please re-setting CPU frequency in CMOS setup

How can I fix this error without having to replace any hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all the places I found after googling this error, I only found one that actually had a solution that worked and did not require a hardware change.

The solution is an easy adjustment in the bios settings and was found at [uncoolcentral.com](http://www.uncoolcentral.com/please-re-setting.htm)

Enter the bios then change the "Halt On" setting to "No Errors". These are the steps as listed on uncoolcentral.com:

> 1. Head into your BIOS. For me, pressing Delete while I'm booting up does the trick. For you, it's likely that too, but there are other keystrokes that'll do the trick. Try, F1, F2, F12, ESC, or some key combos like CTRL+ALT+ESC or CTRL+ALT+S or CTRL+ALT+INS.
> 2. Use your arrow keys to maneuver to "Standard CMOS Features" or something similar. Press the "Enter" key.
> 3. Use the arrows to navigate to "Halt On" and press "Enter"
> 4. Choose "No Errors" with your arrows and press "Enter"
> 5. Get out of the BIOS and be sure you save before exiting.

To me, it seems that this is more of a workaround. Whatever the error is that is halting the boot is now being ignored. Depending on what it is, that may lead to further problems in the future.